# What episode was being referenced by this part of Discovery's season 2 episode 13 recap?

Tags: star-trek, episode-identification, star-trek-discovery

At the beginning of season 2 episode 13, we're given a recap of some scenes I don't remember: Tilly meets an alien woman in what looks like a mess hall aboard a ship. Then we're given this scene:

[image: an alien woman with some blue streaks around her forehead and eyes]

With this verbal exchange:

> **Alien:** I ran away because ... I wasn't ready. I was supposed to become ...
>
> **Tilly:** The queen. Ok.
>
> *(The alien girl, who was standing on the teleporter, is beamed away by Tilly.)*

Unfortunately I don't recall who this is or in what episode these scenes happened. It doesn't correspond to the description for any episode on Netflix and it seems like it would at least be a pretty significant B-plot, and I don't think it was part of the arc of season 2 episode 4.

What episode was this recap covering?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That recap is about the first meeting between Ensign Tilly and the future Queen of Xahea, Her Majesty Me Hani Ika Hali Ka Po, which happens in **[Star Trek: Short Treks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Short_Treks) - Episode 1x01 - "Runaway"**

Comment: First I've heard of "Star Trek: Short Treks". So now we have a show only available online with a spinoff show only available online, which is apparently required viewing for the first show.

Comment: Those are at netflix too.

Comment: It they were going to be essential to the plot, they should have at least labeled them Star Trek: Discovery Short Treks. It's not like you had to watch DS9 to know what was going on in Voyager or TNG.

Comment: @Thunderforge: while I'd mostly agree with you, tbh this is a very bland case. Having seen this short is not required at all, the character get introduced to the audience quite clearly, all the background explained immediately, and the recap at the beginning, well...it recaps as expected. So there is no bit of information missing from not having seen the short itself.

Comment: @Oni not on UK Netflix last time I checked. Though I'd be delighted to find I was wrong.

Comment: @Jontia: They are part of Discovery itself, not a separated thing, and you have to select them from the screen where you can choose which season to watch. But if you are using the Netflix app on a PC then it doesn't show them in the list, the same way you can't see trailers and other additional stuff.